# What are the resource dependencies for a thread in a process?

Tags: linux, multithreading, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have written a C++ code that creates n number of threads inside a process. It works when the number of threads created is 6 or less than 6, when I try to create 7 threads, the process crashes.
What are the reasons for this?
[The number of threads when in my process when 6 threads are created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1LcD.png) - 7

[Stack size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxsAV.png) 16384

[Maximum Threads allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nGKH.png) - 6787

[Running threads including 7 spawned by my process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc7YD.png) - 91

[Error that occurs when I try to create 7 threads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNkIa.png)

Code snippet which I am using to create threads:

```
pthread_t *thread; int iret1; uint8_t i; char commandBuffer[8192];
if(argc <=1) 
{
    DEBUG("pass rasp system id\n");
    return -1;
}
DEBUG("SETTING SYSTEM TIME\n");
system("sudo date -s \"$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z\"");
DEBUG("Initializing wiring pi\n");
wiringPiSetup();
usleep(1000000);
DEBUG("Initialized wiring pi\n");
thread = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*TOTAL_I2CBUSLINES); 
if (thread == NULL)
{
    DEBUG("out of memory\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


/* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */
for(i = 0; i < TOTAL_I2CBUSLINES;i++)
{
    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread[i], NULL, ina219Read_thread_func, (void*) &gdc[i]);
    if(iret1)
    {
     fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",iret1);
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    DEBUG("\nSuccesfully created I2C line for: %d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are using two arrays 'thread' and 'gdc'. See if their indices are out of bound.

Comment: Nope, the indices are not out of bound.